# Checkboxes not accepting input when combined with this find function

Tags: jquery, checkbox, find

These checkboxes stop accepting any input when combined with the function below. I've posted a fiddle demonstrating the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/32/

HTML

```
<ul id="attributes-Colors">
    <li><input type=checkbox name="color[]" value="Blue" data-color="Blue">Blue</li>
    <li><input type=checkbox name="color[]" value="Red" data-color="Red">Red</li>
    <li><input type=checkbox name="color[]" value="Black" data-color="Black">Black</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var selected = [];
    $('#attributes-Colors *').click(function () {
        var attrColor = $(this).data('color');
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $this.parent().removeClass("active");
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(attrColor),1);
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().addClass("active");
            selected.push(attrColor);
        }
        $("#content").find("*").hide();
        $.each(selected, function(index,item) {
            $('#content').find('[data-color ~="' + item + '"]').show();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: did u try taking out `return false` and return appropriate to the situation?

Comment: @SrinivasR - Taking out return false fixed it :-) btw - I'm not sure what you meant by 'return appropriate' - is that a setting that I'm just not familiar with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `return false` in your click handler the checkboxes will respond.

Comment: That fixed it :-D Can I drop it entirely, or do I need to replace it with something else? I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm going to be filtering by several other data-attributes at the same time.

Comment: You don't need to return a value in your click handler unless you specifically want to prevent the default action in specific cases.